# ASP.NET AJAX Control toolkit file upload

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I'm having some difficulty implementing the ajax control toolkit file upload. This is what i have coming up and the following is my code. I'm sorry for using VB, i was forced. If you know a C# solution please provide it and i will convert the code. Thank you

[image: a busy cat]

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.vb" Inherits="AMS.WebForm2" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server" />

    <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Image ID="loader" runat="server"
        ImageUrl="~/loading.gif" Style="display: None" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind

```
Imports System.Web.Script.Serialization
Imports AjaxControlToolkit

Public Class WebForm2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub UploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs)
    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("Files/") + e.FileName
    AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(path)
End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UploadComplete method will never be called because it is never handled. Add the UploadComplete event of the control like so:

```
Protected Sub UploadComplete(sender As Object, e As AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs) Handles AjaxFileUpload1.UploadComplete
    Dim path As String = Server.MapPath("Files/") + e.FileName
    AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(path)
End Sub
```

Since the file upload control is only saving the file to a temp location at this point since your handler is never called, I believe the error you're getting is related to not setting an **HTTP handler**. Otherwise, please specify the error.

Straight from the sample on the ajaxtoolkit site:

> The AjaxFileUpload control uses an HTTP Handler named
>   AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd This handler has the type
>   AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler. You must add this handler to
>   your Web.Config file in order for the AjaxFileUpload control to work.
>
> Here's the Web.Config configuration that you must add:
>
> ```
> <httpHandlers>
>     <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
>       type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
>       AjaxControlToolkit"/>
> </httpHandlers>
> ```
>
> For IIS7:
>
> ```
> <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
> <handlers>
>     <add name="AjaxFileUploadHandler" verb="*" 
>       path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
>       type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
>       AjaxControlToolkit"/>
> </handlers>
> ```

http://www.asp.net/AjaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AjaxFileUpload/AjaxFileUpload.aspx

Comment: thank you, it worked. Do you know how I can capture the bytes of that file so i can store it as binary in the database?

Answer (score 1):

You must add the following in web.config to make it work.

```
<system.web>
    ....
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="AjaxFileUploadHandler.axd"
          type="AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadHandler, 
          AjaxControlToolkit"/>
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```